# RTU in Python 3.8, send_message fails intermittently

Tags: serial-port

- window10 x64
- cpu : 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900   2.40 GHz
- ram : 16.0GB
- python version : 3.8
- umodbus version : 1.0.4
- serial baudrate : 115200

code :

```
from umodbus.client.serial import rtu
...
while True:
    rtu.send_message(msg, serial_port)
    time.sleep(120)
    ...
```

error message:

```
rtu.send_message(msg, serial_port)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\umodbus\client\serial\rtu.py", line 213, in send_message
    serial_port.flush()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 345, in flush
    while self.out_waiting:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 447, in out_waiting
    raise SerialException("ClearCommError failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: ClearCommError failed (OSError(22, 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.', None, 995))
```

This problem occurs randomly.
It works fine the first few times, but then an error occurs as shown above.
help

I changed the USB port several times.